# Unable to SelectElement from Dropdown list - Cannot find dropdow selector

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I'm  unable to locate element: `Dropdown`, the driver simply is unable to find this dropdown thru any selector I tried.

I tried to `FindElement` thru `ID`, `XPath`, `CssSelector` and `ClassName` but I'm unable to simple use the `SelectElement` to locate this.

```
vtenants.VT_USDelselectfld.Click(); //Clicks field to display the dropdown 
Thread.Sleep(500);

IWebElement DropDownElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("dropdown-menu ng-isolate-scope"));
SelectElement SelectElement = new SelectElement(DropDownElement);
IList<IWebElement> elements = SelectElement.Options;
Console.WriteLine(elements.Count);
```

I want to be able to select any option from this dropdown.

[image]

Comment: It should be `By.CssSelector(".dropdown-menu.ng-isolate-scope")`. And you can't use `SelectElement` on `<ul>` tag, only on `<select>` tag.

Comment: You should also post html as text, not as image.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I will in the future upload it as html, do you kno wwhats the best apporach to select an item with the <ul> tag?

Comment: There are many questions and answers on how to select value from non-select dropdown.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Foreach on li elements click into one thats text is equal your required text.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
driver.get("https://www1.hkexnews.hk/search/titlesearch.xhtml?lang=en");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='combobox-field' and @data-value='rbAll']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-value='rbAfter2006']//a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rbAfter2006']//a[contains(text(),'ALL') and @data-value='-2']")).click();
List<WebElement>list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='rbAfter2006']//ul[@class='droplist-items']//a"));
     for(WebElement li:list)
            {
                JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",li);
                if(li.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Constitutional Documents"))
                {

                    li.click();

                }
            }
```